# Gitlab Self-Hosted: ERROR: Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... 308 Permanent Redirect

Tags: java, android, testing, gitlab, jacoco

I am trying to visualize test coverage using jacoco for my Android application with Kotlin and I am following this article for our Gitlab (self-hosted) instance:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/testing/test_coverage_visualization.html#gradle-example

For some reason, Gitlab can't upload the artifacts. Here are some of the errors:

```
./app/build/reports/jacoco/testDebugUnitTestCoverage/testDebugUnitTestCoverage.xml: found 1 matching files and directories 
WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... 308 Permanent Redirect  id=811458 responseStatus=308 Permanent Redirect status=308

WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=invalid argument
WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: were you able to solve the issue ?

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet!

Comment: I only got it to work by removing the default network from the gitlab instance in the docker-compose, such that the runner container doesn't resolve the dns locally...